# NReco.PdfGenerator.WkHtmlToPdfException: exit code: -1073741521

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, nreco

I working on a pdf generator with `NRec PdfGenerator` and it works fine at the start when I working with local, once I package up and deploy to server it fail and show the error message

```
Cannot generate PDF: (exit code: -1073741521) ---> NReco.PdfGenerator.WkHtmlToPdfException: (exit code: -1073741521)
```

I not sure whats causing it and I believe is not related to the code itself, and I could find any related post or article that about the exit code shown.

Is there anyway to fix this error?

Any advice to this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This error means that wkhtmltopdf was crushed, most likely because some Universal C runtime libs are not installed on the server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48678977/nreco-pdf-genreation-error-dot-net

Answer (score 0):

As Vitaliy Fedorchenko commented, the problem, in the compatible operating systems, can be solved by installing the missing required Universal C runtime libs ( https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows ).